# i want to update my sqlite and firebase database every hour?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, background-process, android-8.0-oreo

I want to update my local sqlite and firebase database every hour. But I can't use the broadcast receiver as it was ban in android o. I can't use Job scheduler and work manager as it is a timebase application. I don't want to foreground service because it will use lots of resources and required to show a notification that I can't show.

Comment: Why don't you use `AlarmManager`?

Comment: @AnggrayudiH I tried it doesn't fire every time when the phone is in  doze mode

Comment: Use `RTC_WAKEUP`. It should works.

Comment: @AnggrayudiH in deep doze mode android will ignore all the wakeup call